# Structuring A Linq Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've searched the site and also googled but to no avail. Perhaps I'm tired and hence googling the wrong thing, I don't know. But I'm my wits end and could really use some help or advice. I'm building a touring site using ASP.NET MVC 4, and I've encountered a problem with the correct query to use to get all the information I need from the database.

I have a class Safari that stores information about a particular safari. I have another class Highlight that stores information about the highlights of a particular safari. As such, a safari can have several highlights in a one-to-many relationship. I initially had the highlights as a field in Safari of type List, but even then I still had trouble seeding and querying the details for "highlights" and the field "highlights" was not being created in the Safari table, so I made Highlights into a class. I still wasn't able to seed the fields for Highlight, but since the table was created, I was able to do it manually (so I know the table has data).

I want to be able to query the database for not only the availabe safaris, but also their related highlights. I've also included the classes Safari, Highlight, SafarisController and Configuration.

Safari.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public List<Highlight> Highlights { get; set;
```

Highlight.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int SafariId { get; set; }
```

SafarisController.cs

```
    private ToursTravelDb db = new ToursTravelDb();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.Safaris.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Configuration.cs

```
    protected override void Seed(Travel_Site.Models.ToursTravelDb context)
    {
        context.Safaris.AddOrUpdate(
            r => r.Name,
            new Safari 
            { 
                Name = "Tsavo East Safari", 
                Description = "This is a short Kenya safari tour", 
                Location = "Tsavo East National Park", 
                Cost = 1200, 
                Zone = "Nairobi",
                Highlights = new List<string>(new string{
                    "Tsavo East National park", 
                    "Views of local homesteads on safari route.", 
                    "Scenic Tsavo East savannah plains.", 
                    "Elephants, Giraffe, Zebra, Buffalo, Cheetah, Lions etc.", 
                    "Panoramic views of Tsavo East  during  lunch stop."
                })
            },
            new Safari 
            { 
                Name = "Amboseli Overnight Safari", 
                Description = "Camp at the Amboseli National Park. ", 
                Location = "Amboseli National Park", 
                Cost = 1200, 
                Zone = "Nairobi", 
                Highlights = new List<string>(new string{
                    "Amboseli National Park", 
                    "Hippopotatamus", 
                    "Flamingoes"
                })
            }
        );
    }
```

I appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the Safari and not just the Id in your Highlight class. In my experience it is easier to debug such relationships and especially the seed content if you separate them during development.

Safari.cs

```
[Key]
public int SafariId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Zone { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public int Cost { get; set; }
public List<Highlight> Highlights { get; set;  }
```

Highlight.cs

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Safari")]
public int? SafariId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SafariId")]
public virtual Safari Safari { get; set; }
```

Configuration.cs

```
var safaris = new List<Safari>
    {
        new Safari
        {
            Name = "Tsavo East Safari", 
            Description = "This is a short Kenya safari tour", 
            Location = "Tsavo East National Park", 
            Cost = 1200, 
            Zone = "Nairobi"
        },
        new Safari 
        { 
            Name = "Amboseli Overnight Safari", 
            Description = "Camp at the Amboseli National Park. ", 
            Location = "Amboseli National Park", 
            Cost = 1200
        }
    };
safaris.ForEach(i => context.Safaris.Add(i));
context.SaveChanges();

var highlights = new List<Highlight>
    {
        new Highlight
        {
            Content = "Tsavo East National park",
            Safari = (from s in context.Safaris where Name == "Tsavo East Safari" select e)
        }
    };
highlights.ForEach(i => context.Highlights.Add(i));
context.SaveChanges();
```

I hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

A few things that will help with this:

1. Entity Framework can create relationships and create related data by using Navigation Properties.  In Safari.cs, use a generic collection.  e.g. `public virtual ICollection<Highlight> Highlights {get;set;}`
2. It is not necessary to have a navigation property from highlights to safari but it is definitely helpful.
3. When performing a query, use .Include() to "eagerly" load the navigation properties.  e.g.  `var model = db.Safaris.Include(s => s.highlights).ToList();`

Also, your seed method is creating a List of string, not a list of Highlight.